# Size of page Table entry

Tags: operating-systems, paging

The following question was asked by our professor in exam:-

Given a system with 4GB virtual address space and page size 4KB and total physical RAM of size 8KB. What will be the size of the page Table if each entry consumes 4 Bytes. Also the system allows upto 1024 processes to run concurrently.

The answer is:-

For each process no of pages allotted = 4GB/4KB = 2^20. For each page 4 Bytes are used. For each process then there will be 2^22 Bytes consumed. This for 1024 processes will be 2^32 Bytes consumed.

But here I am confused. Each process will have the same no of pages table entries as the no of pages allotted. Here we are filling up the virtual address space of all processes. That is each process is getting alloted 4GB/4KB pages = 2^20 pages. 1024 processes will then have 2^30 pages. But in the RAM there can be at Max 2^21 pages.

My mind was that in worst case each page would be allotted to some process. Each process takes up 4 Bytes then there are 2^21 pages which will make the size 2^23 Bytes.

Any help would be appreciated